# Echoing PHP within ajax success call

Tags: php, ajax

Basically I have two sliders on my page, whenever their value is adjusted they reference a script which returns a JSON array holding values about products which meet the new criteria.

In my success callback I want to call my PHP class which renders my view to the screen ( I am aware that I could probably achieve this effect in Javascript, but I already have a PHP class built which handles all of the required logic, so it would be simpler if there was a shortcut.

My AJAX method looks like this:

```
function update_results(values) 
{
    var json = JSON.stringify(values);
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url:  "./app/core/commands/update_results.php?cache=" + (new Date().getTime()),
       data: { query : json },
       cache: false,
       success: function(data) {
          // Remove the old data from the document
          $('tr').remove();

          // Build the new table rows using the returned data array
          $('table').append("<?php Table t = new Table(data); ?>");

       }
    });
}
```

Calling my Table constructor builds everything I need just by passing the JSON array I recieve back from my AJAX call, however nothing is being rendered to the screen at the moment - is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You need to render the table on the server and push the html to javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on the server...JavaScript on the client... `"<?php Table t = new Table(data); ?>"`
 does not magically work with the Ajax call. The server should be returning the table when you make the Ajax call.

Comment: +1. at the very least, the server should respond to with the table markup during the first request, and the ajax call should return the data to populate the table with.

Comment: Yep I've got it working by sending the table back via PHP now, thanks guys.